# mkdir: /data: Read-only file system

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I installed MongoDB using these instructions:

https://github.com/mongodb/homebrew-brew

However, I cannot connect to a Mongo shell when I run `mongo`.

How do I connect to the Mongo shell?

I was made aware of `mongosh`, when I run the `mongosh` command after installing it, I get `connect ECONNREFUSED`.

When I run a `ps -ef | grep mongod | grep -v grep | wc -l | tr -d ''` it shows zero process is running, which would logically explain why I cannot connect, but then what do I do when I run `brew services start mongodb-community` and it says it starts but zero process when I look into it.

I don't know if `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` is what is missing for this to run correctly, but when I attempt to run that step, I get `mkdir: /data: Read-only file system`.

So I placed the directory in `/Users/<username>/data/db` and then ran `mongod --dbpath=/Users/<username>/data/db` and nothing.

Comment: @dododo, it does not, I installed `mongosh` and now I get `zsh: command not found: mongosh`.

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@4.2/bin` are these binaries placed here?

Comment: @dododo, that's inside of my `.zshrc` file.

Comment: Check the MongoDB logfile

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, there is no **mongodb** inside of `/var/log/`

Comment: @dododo, missing mongo shell is a common problem in MongoDB version 6.0 - however, it is not always the correct answer.

Comment: Why did you not follow the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I did, thats almost identical to the Homebrew github instructions, but it would never start up. I just learned that its because I have to add `sudo` to run the command to start up the mongo daemon. That's never occurred to me on my personal machine. Fun stuff whenever I have to work with someone else's machine that has been assigned to me.

Comment: `/data/db` is the default folder when no `dbPath` is provided. When mongod is installed as a service, then you should have a config file where `dbPath` might be different. According documentation config file should be `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` or `/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, you are correct, what I was missing from that `mongod ---dbpath=/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` is that it needed `sudo` prefixed, but I just tried the path you suggested and its not working, what works for me is referencing where I placed `/data/db`

Comment: You used option `--dbpath` with the **configuration file** - not the path where data is stored! And I recommend not to mix [Configuration File](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and [Command-Line Options](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/configuration-file-settings-command-line-options-mapping/) - use only one of them!